# i want to modify this SQL statement to return only distinct rows of a column

Tags: sql, select, mysqli, distinct

```
select 
      picks.`fbid`, 
      picks.`time`, 
      categories.`name` as cname, 
      options.`name` as oname, 
      users.`name` 
   from 
      picks 
         left join categories 
            on (categories.`id` = picks.`cid`) 
         left join options 
            on (options.`id` = picks.oid) 
         left join users 
            on (users.fbid = picks.`fbid`) 
   order by 
      time desc
```

that query returns a result that like:

[image]

my question is.... I would like to modify the query to select only DISTINCT fbid's. (perhaps the first row only sorted by time)

can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
      p2.fbid,
      p2.time,
      c.`name` as cname, 
      o.`name` as oname, 
      u.`name` 
   from
      ( select p1.fbid, 
               min( p1.time ) FirstTimePerID
           from picks p1
           group by p1.fbid ) as FirstPerID

         JOIN Picks p2
            on FirstPerID.fbid = p2.fbid
           AND FirstPerID.FirstTimePerID = p2.time

            LEFT JOIN Categories c
               on p2.cid = c.id

            LEFT JOIN Options o
               on p2.oid = o.id

            LEFT JOIN Users u
               on p2.fbid = u.fbid
   order by 
      time desc
```

I don't know why you originally had LEFT JOINs, as it appears that all picks must be associated with a valid category, option and user... I would then remove the left, and change them to INNER joins instead.

The first inner query grabs for each fbid, the FIRST entry time which will result in a single entity for the FBID.  From that, it re-joins to the picks table for the same ID and timeslot... then continues for the rest of the category, options, users join criteria of that single entry.

Comment: thanks for the heads up DRapp. I ran your script and really close, it's working as it was, however still not providing distinct FBID's (it's still showing multiple rows of the same FBID). I feel like this really close. any adjustments you can see for this?

Comment: @Rees, Due to duplication of times, that might be the issue.  Is there a unique primary key on the PICKS table?  If so, just change the MIN( TIME) to MIN( PRIMARYKEY ) and join on the PRIMARY KEY matching the MIN(PRIMARYKEY) instead.

Answer (score 1):

2 options, you could write a group by clause.
Or you could write a nested query joined back to itself to get pertinent info.

Nested aliased table:

```
SELECT
n.fBids
FROM
MyTable t 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT fBids
FROM MyTable) n
ON n.ID = t.ID
```

Or group by option

```
SELECT fBId from MyTable
GROUP BY fBID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select picks.`fbid`, picks.`time`, categories.`name` as cname,
options.`name` as oname, users.`name` from picks left join categories
on (categories.`id` = picks.`cid`) left join options on (options.`id` = picks.oid)
left join users on (users.fbid = picks.`fbid`)
order by time desc GROUP BY picks.`fbid`
```

Comment: This won't work because categories.name is not part of an aggregate.

Comment: When posting code, please format it as such (e.g. highlight it and press the code button `{}`, or indent by 4 spaces)

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    picks.fbid,
    MIN(picks.time) as first_time,
    MAX(picks.time) as last_time
from
    picks
group by
    picks.fbid    
order by
    MIN(picks.time) desc
```

However, if you want only distinct `fbid's` you cannot display `cname` and other columns at the same time.